Заполнить пропущенные значения в столбце dataframe значением подстроки из другого столбца
Третий день пытаюсь решить элементарнейшую задачу - заполнить пропущенные значения в столбце dataframe значением подстроки из другого столбца. Поля строковые. Перечитал кучу документации и примеров. В итоге вымучил вот что
def podstroka(y):
    return 'J' + y[14:]

df_FileOne['US'] = df_FileOne['US'].apply(lambda x: podstroka(df_FileOne['Debet'].astype(str)) if df_FileOne[df_FileOne['US'].isnull()] else df_FileOne['US'])

Но не работает.
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.
Помогите, специалисту тут на решение задачи - только время на набор строчки с кодом.


Пожалуйста, не используйте для кода, данных или текста ошибок картинки. См. почему.

Время пришлось потратить не только на набор строчки с кодом, но и на создание примера данных. Не постите данные и код картинками.
df = pd.DataFrame({'US': [None, None, 'J12345', 'J4565285'], 'Debet': ['10101010101010101', '4747474747474747', '898989898989898', '46584512513512']})
df.loc[mask, 'US'] = 'J' + df.loc[(mask := df.US.isna()), 'Debet'].str[:14]
print(df)

                US              Debet
0  J10101010101010  10101010101010101
1  J47474747474747   4747474747474747
2           J12345    898989898989898
3         J4565285     46584512513512


Да, спасибо, работает. Только надо не [:14], а [14:], но это мелочь.

Плохо, что не понимаю, как это работает.
Лет 30 назад в Clarion for DOS всё было просто и понятно - перебор всех записей файла в цикле и замена значения одного поля значением, сформированным из другого, по условию .
SET LOOP UNTIL EOF(FILE)
NEXT(FILE)
IF US='' THEN US:='J'+SUBSTRING(DEBET,14,20)
PUT(FILE)
END ; END
На 5 минут работы, всё прозрачно и понятно. Простите за стариковское брюзжание, по-любому - спасибо, честно.
